# detecting word boundary with regex in data frame in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, word-boundary

I have a data.frame named `all` that has a column of factors, these factors include `"word"`,`"nonword"` and some others. My goal is to select only the rows that have the factor value "word".

My solution `grep("\bword\b",all[,5])` returns nothing.

How come word boundaries are not recognized?

Comment: Why not just `all %>% filter(column %in% "word")`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In R, you need two times `\`:

```
grep("\\bword\\b", all[5])
```

Alternative solutions:

```
grep("^word$", all[5])

which(all[5] == "word")
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work, thank you. Do you know why "\bword\b" does not work in this case?

Comment: +1 The pattern `grep("^word$", ...)` will match the whole string, not just words.. even though here they don't make a difference.