# Filtering Rows, Factors in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

[Filtering row which contains a certain string using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr)

Hi guys,

V2 is a column, factor classification.

I am trying to filter the following but I get 0 values:

```
MSFT <- dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("$MSFT", V2) )
```

Strangely, this works:

```
MSFT <- dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("MSFT", V2) )
```

But I want `MSFT` specifically and not `MSFTXXX` or `MSFT` e.t.c

Thanks :)

Comment: escape the `$` (i.e. `\\$`)

Comment: `$` means "end of string"---so stick it where you want the end to be: `"MSFT$"`. "$MSFT" is looking for a line that ends, and then after the end has "MSFT".

Comment: ah, i thought it was more `$MSFT` like a stock quote. you'll need to add regex word boundaries if you want `MSFT` anywhere in the 140 chars.

Comment: Cool Thanks ! @hrbrmstr, yup it is like a hastag in twitter, I'm dealing with twitter data during the crash in 2008-2010. I managed to do the following:                                                                                                   $GE' <- dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("\\bGE$\\b", V2) )  to get the exact filter :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906003/detecting-word-boundary-with-regex-in-data-frame-in-r