# Filtering in R with punctuation characters

Tags: regex, r, filter, dplyr, grepl

I have a column of data set that looks like this:

```
$abc.MSFT

$MSFT

$msft

$abcMSFTxyz
```

I want the following output:

```
$MSFT  

$msft
```

My attempt at filtering:

```
dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("\\bMMM$\\b", ignore.case = TRUE, V2))
```

returns:

```
$abc.MSFT

$MSFT

$msft
```

or

```
dplyr::filter(Tweets,grepl("^$MMM$", ignore.case = TRUE, V2))
```

returns:

Comment: try `grepl("^\\$msft$", ignore.case = TRUE, x)`. The dollar sign is a special character in regex. If you want a literal `$` matched, you must escape the character with backslashes.

Comment: @ Pierre \\bMMM$\\b works but it cannot ignore punctuation characters at the start of the string. I want it to ignore all other punctuation characters except for the $ character.

Comment: @ Pierre, okay I'll try. Thanks

Comment: If `"\\bMMM$\\b"` matches `"MSFT"` for you then I know nothing about regex and you should be the one answering questions. I'd be really interested in seeing the code example. (Not just you saying "it returns..")

Comment: @ Pierre Thanks your solution works!

Comment: @ Pierre http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906003/detecting-word-boundary-with-regex-in-data-frame-in-r , I used that example to try :)

Comment: That method could work too, but you have to remember to include the backslashes `"^\\b\\$msft\\b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach it:

```
x <- c("$abc.MSFT", "$MSFT", "$msft", "$abcMSFTxyz")
Tweets <- data.frame(V2=x, stringsAsFactors=F)
Tweets
#           V2
#1   $abc.MSFT
#2       $MSFT
#3       $msft
#4 $abcMSFTxyz

#your way
dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("\\bMMM$\\b", ignore.case = TRUE, V2))
[1] V2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

#another way
dplyr::filter(Tweets, grepl("^\\$msft$", ignore.case = TRUE, V2))
     V2
1 $MSFT
2 $msft
```

From [regex help](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html):

> ..there are 12 characters with special meanings: the backslash \, the
>   caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or
>   pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus
>   sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), and the
>   opening square bracket [, the opening curly brace {, These special
>   characters are often called "metacharacters".

And the fix:

> If you want to use any of these characters as a literal in a regex,
>   you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match 1+1=2,
>   the correct regex is 1\\+1=2. Otherwise, the plus sign has a special
>   meaning.

Research regular expressions. They are worth the time to learn whatever language you wish to program in.