# R: using \\b and \\B in regex

Tags: r, regex, string

I read about regex and came accross word boundaries. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex) that is about the difference between `\b` and `\B`. Using the code from this question does not give the expected output. Here:

```
grep("\\bcat\\b", "The cat scattered his food all over the room.", value= TRUE)
# I expect "cat" but it returns the whole string.

grep("\\B-\\B", "Please enter the nine-digit id as it appears on your color - coded pass-key.", value= TRUE)
# I expect "-" but it returns the whole string.
```

I use the code as described in the question but with two backslashes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906003/detecting-word-boundary-with-regex-in-data-frame-in-r). Using one backslash does not work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use `regexpr` and `regmatches` to get the match. `grep` gives where it hits. You can also use `sub`.

```
x <- "The cat scattered his food all over the room."
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\bcat\\b", x))
#[1] "cat"
sub(".*(\\bcat\\b).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "cat"

x <- "Please enter the nine-digit id as it appears on your color - coded pass-key."
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\B-\\B", x))
#[1] "-"
sub(".*(\\B-\\B).*", "\\1", x)
#[1] "-"
```

For more than 1 match use `gregexpr`:

```
x <- "1abc2"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[0-9]", x))
#[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2"
```

Comment: I like that your answer uses R base. I had another example where the pattern occurs multiple times in the string. In `stringr` we can do `str_extract_all("1abc2", "[0-9]")` for multiple occurance (will return 1 *and* 2). But `regmatches("1abc2", regexpr("[0-9]", "1abc2"))` returns only 1. Is there a way to do this with your approach?

Comment: Yes: Use `gregexpr` instead of `regexpr`. I added it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`grep`returns the whole string because it just looks to see if the match is present **in** the string. If you want to extract `cat`, you need to use other functions such as `str_extract`from package `stringr`:

```
str_extract("The cat scattered his food all over the room.", "\\bcat\\b") 
[1] "cat"
```

The difference betweeen `b`and `B`is that `b`marks word boundaries whereas `B`is its negation. That is, `\\bcat\\b` matches only if `cat` is separated by white space whereas `\\Bcat\\B` matches only if `cat` is inside a word. For example:

```
str_extract_all("The forgot his education and scattered his food all over the room.", "\\Bcat\\B") 
[[1]]
[1] "cat" "cat"
```

These two matches are from `education` and `scattered`.